# Chrome won't stop caching scripts, even when caching disabled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching

I am working on a PHP and JavaScript app. I make modifications to my JS, refresh Chrome, and it is not using the most recent script. It appears to be caching.

I have "disable caching" checked in Dev Tools, and I even tried an extension [Cache Killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en), but Chrome STILL caches my script.

This behavior is not occurring in Safari or Firefox, without any plugins.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you opened the dev tools to ensure that Chrome is pulling it from the cache (on the network panel)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually force the browser to load a fresh copy of a URL by making it "new" using something like a new parameter value in the URL.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", "yourfile.js?random=" + new Date());
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

This will load a new instance of the file "yourfile.js" everytime because we append the date and time of "now", which will always be new.

(this post was written as an answer because I cannot write comments at the moment)

Comment: this is ultimately what I ended up doing (although I went with `rand()`), but it seems really strange to me.... Why is Chrome using cached copies despite specifying "do not cache" on not just one, but several fronts?

Comment: Please note that although rand() is random, a value may actually be returned more than once, which means Chrome will show an old/cached file - it is unlikely to happen though. Using the datetime ( ``new Date()`` ) will always return a new value since time will always pass. I am unable to explain Chrome caches the files despite the fact that it is not supposed to. Try clearing cache and load the page again. There is always the chance that you've run into a bug.

Comment: I am running Yosemite which is still relatively new, so perhaps it's a bug relating to the current Chrome build and Yosemite. I did not encounter this issue on Mavericks before updating, come to think of it. It's strange because it only appears to happen on my server at work, and only with Chrome, not on personal servers.

Comment: I just got a new Mac with Yosemite installed. Lo, Google won't let go of the cached Javascript files! "Disable Cache" is checked. It was even coming up with versions of files a few iterations back in some cases. The only way to make it quit was to append a querystring. Why, Chrome?